# Css class selector

Tags: css

I want to select a div whose `class = "c" & id = "i"` :

```
 .c
 {
   color: red;
   border:1px;
   font-size:25px;
   background-color: yellow;
   width:200px;
 }

 <div id="i" class="c">change</div>
```

now how can i change only the width from class="c" properties for this div?

Comment: do you need answer only using css or using jquery also no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
.c#i { width:400px }
```

This changes the width of the div with class `c` AND id `i`

Answer (score 1):

> now how can i change only the width from class="c" properties for this
>   div?

To select a div with class `c`:

```
div.c {width: yourValue;}
```

To change a div with class `c` AND id `i`:

```
.c#i {width: yourValue;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can do this

```
#i.c{
width:xxx; //your value
}
```