# jQuery target only li tags where a element have a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to target only li elements where the a tag has a specific class?

for example:

```
<li> <a href="#" class="mobile-only">link</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" class="other-class">link</a> </li>
```

Can I just target the li where a has class "mobile-only"?

Comment: `$('a.mobile-only').parent('li');` should do the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Css class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794610/css-class-selector)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can access the parent of anchor tag with class `mobile-only`

```
$( "a.mobile-only" ).parent();
```

or you can use [parent pseudo selector](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/), but there are performance concerns

```
li a:parent { background: none; }
```

js Code `$( "li a:parent" )`

also the [has selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/1984039)

```
li:has(a.mobile-only) { background: none; }
```

js Code `$( "li:has(a.mobile-only)" )`

Comment: `$( "li:has(a.mobile-only)")` This will work. No need to complex the selector by specifying child selector.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy sure, will make the change.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x0rayv1f/ Jquery version is working, but css version is not working. https://jsfiddle.net/x0rayv1f/2/ Can you tell the reason why?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy which version of browser you are using, can you run this and let me know http://css4-selectors.com/browser-selector-test/

Comment: `chrome 48.0.2564.116 m` The most recent one. Is it working for you?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy No, and that site is telling that my version (43) doesn't support this yet.

Comment: Thank you for support...your answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do with jQuery.

Just do:

```
$("a.mobile-only").parents("li")
```

Comment: Can I just target the `li` where `a` has class "mobile-only"?

Comment: $("li.mobile-only") will search for <li class"mobile-only">

Comment: `.parent()` would be more appropriate here than `.parents()`.

Comment: @DanielBeck is right as this may be nested within other `li`'s

Comment: parent() is more appropriate if you're sure that the li is the direct parent. Otherwise parents() is better.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('a.mobile-only').parent("li")
```

Comment: That would make the current selection the `a` and not the `li`

Comment: @JamieSterling:yeah,my bad.Corrected the answer